# Context Engine shows only a small list of claim store values

Tags: content-delivery, 2013, context-engine

I've installed the context engine into my SDL Tridion 2013 GA content delivery website.  I'm not quite sure where I got the installation from as I can't find it online (i must have found it somewhere!), I see from the database properties file i'm running the following version:

```
HSQL Database Engine 2.2.8
Wed Oct 30 08:08:18 PKT 2013
version=2.2.8
modified=no
```

My problem is that i'm only seeing the following created claims:

```
taf:claim:context:browser:model = Chrome
taf:claim:context:browser:version = 31
taf:claim:context:device:model = Other
taf:claim:context:os:model = Windows 7
```

I was expecting a larger amount of information to be created such as pixel density, viewport size etc.

I'm suspecting this is because i'm using an early version and need to perform a re-install, but I was wondering if there are some conditions in which claims can not be created?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that the '`Repository`' folder which contains the CE database was located within the `/Bin/Lib` folder and not directly under the `/Bin` folder.  Moving this folder up a directory has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I see 27 claims from the Context Engine.

It will always create the claims, even when it cannot determine their value (that's what the Default values are for).

My guess: you're not reading the right data.